# Android APK problem

Tags: android, apk

while i compile my application on sdk and on my phone i see the same application 3 times over the phone. Only 1 of them works and the other 2 throws exeption. this is the printscreen of the problem.[image: There are 3 YayinAkisi apk why?]

Comment: Did you change the package name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds very much like you've marked all the activities in your application with categor `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` --- that's what makes the activities show up in the launcher. Naturally, if one of your activities gets launched when it's not expecting to be, it'll likely crash. But you'll have to post more info (like a stack trace) to tell for sure.

Answer (score 2):

When working on an emulator, you can choose to wipe all user data on boot from the AVD manager. You might want to give that a try.

Also, as Kartik said, if you changed the package name of the application, it will install alongside the previous versions as Android sees it as a new application and not as an upgrade.